# How to hide the notification about stories in my feed in Quora?

Tags: notifications, quora

Quora keeps nagging me to read about stories in my feed. I want to hide them all.
[image: image description]

I have unsubscribed all the topics on my feed, except the compulsory one:

[image: image description]